# Problems with Pointer<Class> in Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've been using **Parse.com** for two months, but this is the first time I get a stupid error which I can't figure out.

I've been working in an app for iOS, but in the beginning I've been working with my own user. Now I registered other users and I want to fetch them from the server.

Well, I add one object in the table `Changes`, where I have a `user` property which is a `Pointer<User>` (it's not `_User`, but User, it's custom, just an object). Well, when I try to fetch all the rows I have, the one that I have with my user are ok:

[image]

so in my debug console is like :

[image]

but when I fetch other users:

[image]

my debug console is:

[image]

so there's not any variable!!!! :(

This is my code:

```
PFQuery *closestChanges = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Changes"];
[closestChanges whereKey:@"coordinates" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinKilometers:0.5f];


[closestChanges findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *changes, NSError *error) {

    arrayChanges0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayChanges1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (changes == nil && changes.count == 0) {
        [_tableView reloadData];
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < changes.count; i++) {
        PFObject *currentChange = [changes objectAtIndex:i];
        PFObject *user = [currentChange valueForKey:@"user"]; // here my user is null when it's other users.

        PFObject *changeToStore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Changes"];
        [changeToStore setValue:currentChange[@"changetype"] forKey:@"type"];
        [changeToStore setValue:currentChange[@"quantity"] forKey:@"quantity"];
        [changeToStore setValue:currentChange[@"date"] forKey:@"enddata"];
        [changeToStore setValue:user forKey:@"user"];


        if ([currentChange[@"changetype"] intValue] == 0)
        [arrayChanges0 addObject:changeToStore];
        else
        [arrayChanges1 addObject:changeToStore];
    }

    [_tableView reloadData];


}];
```

Is there anything wrong I'm doing by adding new users???

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Where are you doing this logging? When using a user you get from accessing the pointer? Where is that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch a pointer type from a table, you will only get back the metadata which is `objectId`. You need to call `- (instancetype)includeKey:(NSString *)key` in order to get all the data back from `Changes` table. If you query directly from `User` table, you will get all the data. But in this case, you `User` object is a subdocument from `Changes` objects.

Add this line before performing querying:

`[closestChanges includeKey:@"user"]`

Comment: And now... to be a complete 100% genius (you already are!)... why the hell was I able to fetch the user with some users and not with another one ?? Thank you very much. I'm not very interested in this last question, but it's something I'd like to know for curiosity =)

Comment: Maybe you accidentally fetch it directly from `User` table? lol. I am glad this helps.